# start gnome screen recorder command line

Tags: gnome, 19.10, screencast

The keyboard shortcut to start the built-in screen recorder in Gnome is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. For some reason it is not working on my system.

Is it possible to start it from the command line instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can see your gnome screen recorder (screencast) shortcut keys with:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast
```

In my Ubuntu 19.10 system, it shows `['<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R']` which is the default keys.

Maybe your system is configured to use other keys, but you can map to whatever key you want or the default keys you mentioned above as follows:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screencast your-keymap
```

I don't think you can runt it from command-line and I don't know why it is so hidden on gnome-shell.

Comment: That command returns `['<Ctrl><Shift><Alt>R']` but when I press that key combination nothing happens.

Comment: I tried changing it to '<Shift><Alt>R'] but still it doesn't start a screencast.

Comment: If it makes any difference I installed and am using vanilla gnome.